# How to run Html and Url helpers when use Html.Raw - ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm trying to get some html part from database, and when i use `Html.Raw(htmlString)` helpers render as string instead of execute it.

Exemple:

```
@{
    var html = "<img src=\"@Url.Asset(\"img/banner-example.png\")\">";
}

@Html.Raw(html);
```

And that render

```
<img src="@Url.Asset("img/banner-exemple.png")">
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: @Html. Raw prints the original string, for example without escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated to expect the engine to run the code in Raw output.  Instead just create the string you're looking for.

```
@{
    var html = "<img src=\"" + Url.Asset("img/banner-example.png") + "\">";
}
```